# Do I have bad topology?

Tags: topology

I created my first character in Blender but I feel like the topology isn't right. Can you please give me suggestions for improvement?

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it seems rather good, I would say 3 things:

- For the face, the classic topology includes the bottom of the nose and the mouth within the same edge loops circle, it makes the modeling and the animation easier, but if your face works as it is, do you really need that?
- You have 4 vertical rows of faces going from neck to pubis, that seem useless, you could simplify that with one of these two methods.
- To animate and have a nice bend, you'll probably need to add some edge loops where the bend will happen, for example around the elbow.

[image]